# To level up the accuracy

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

```
That method can help you to level up the accuracy
```

What I meant to say is that method can help you to improve the accuracy, is the sentence above grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: I think you should write what you mean: "That method can help you to improve the accuracy." What you posted suggests that there are different components, with varying accuracy, which will be evened out by "that method."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no, your original sentence is not idiomatic. You're taking slang from video games and trying to use it in another context. Sometimes using terminology from another context like this helps people to understood because it creates a useful analogy, or is clever and makes an amusing metaphor. But in this case, I don't think it accomplishes either of those things.

If you want to say "it improves the accuracy", why not just say "it improves the accuracy"?

Answer (score 1):

*Level up* is a phrase derived from video games and is appropriate to use when talking about things you do in a video game or possibly if you're trying to use video-game terms to relate to others.  Outside of those contexts it will sound awkward.